# Coldfusion framework application configuration

Tags: coldfusion

We have one legacy ColdFusion framework application and we have recently changed the domain name of the application. The issue is some of the menu items are redirecting to the old domain URL.

Here I'm trying to see if anyone can help me to find out where the configuration files reside. How can I find the application property files and change the new domain URL to the new address?

I have tried to run the search operation on the `wwwroot` folder and found some  400+ static entries are encoded in the .cfm files.

Thank you,
Regards,
Venkat

Comment: You'll have to change each static entry.

Comment: Do have any code associated with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found the a table which have link to the menu folder, updating the table with new links fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You may have a few options:

**Find and Replace**

Just use your editor to find and replace `www.oldSite.com` withe `www.newSite.com`.

**Relative Paths**

If the links are directing to `https://www.oldSite.com/some/url.cfm`, you should be able to change them to `/some/url.cfm` so they all act off the root of the site. You also have the option to globally set a `<base href="https://www.newSite.com">` in a (cross fingers) global layout file, so that you all links are relative to the new domain.

**Set Global Variables**

In your `Application.cfc` or `Application.cfc` at the root of the application, you can set a global variable: `<cfset application.domain = "https://www.newSite.com">` and then you'll still have to find and replace the old domain string and replace it with a reference to the new variable:

from `<a href="https://www.oldSite.com/some/url.cfm">`

to `<a href="#application.domain#/some/url.cfm">`, but you'll also need to make sure this is wrapped with `<cfoutput>` tags to render the value of the variable.

**Don't Forget Emails**

You should also check for hard-coded email addresses throughout the code base. They'll be referencing the old domain as well. You can create new global variables for them as well.